# How to implement login in a Backbone app

Tags: authentication, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app where we know start to implement the login. Till now I we had no login and the app starts with creating all relevant models and collection on start. Now the API demands a session cookie to response.

What would be the better solution:

1. having a login.html that forward to the app.html after a successful login
2. having the login to be part of the Backbone app with an own route

In both solution, how can I prevent that the user sees the login dialog again, just by pressing the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the standard way of login handling, a simple login page separated from the application.

`/admin/` in this route I have a simple middleware checking for the user session if the user is not authenticated, he is redirected over `/admin/login`.

Once the user obtains a valid session he can freely go to `/admin/` where my application resides. The same apply when you need to authenticate users with some OpenID or OAuth provider.

There is no use in handling authentication in the browser since it's too much simple to handle it in your backend. In fact in my backend I have only three standard routes:

```
/* accessible routes */
/admin/login
/* protected routes: */
/admin/
/admin/(...)
/admin/logout
```

For the back button issue, you just need to know if the user already have a valid session token, then redirect/trigger to the right route (beware of redirection loops)